# When do you need to use #include in c++

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

I've been programming for awhile now and one thing I've still never quite figured out is exactly when you need to `#include` something. I know to be safe you can do it whenever you use something declared in another file. However at times I find that I can remove an `#include` and everything will still compile just fine. From what I can tell this is because other files being included already are including the external definition. There are two particular cases I'm interested in knowing the behavior for:

1. Say we have three .h/.cc pairs: f1.h/.cc, f2.h/.cc, and f3.h/.cc. If f2.h/.cc includes f1.h and f3.h/.cc includes f2.h is it ever necessary for f3.h/.cc to include f1.h or will all of f1.h's definitions be visible to the f3 files when it is included in f2?
2. Once again say we have three .h/.cc pairs: f1.h/.cc, f2.h/.cc, and f3.h/.cc. If f2 includes f1 and f2 includes f1 and then f3 includes f1 or f2 will the "circular linkage" between and f1 and f2 cause a problem?

Do you know of any good resources online I can read to better understand how including something in one file affects subsequent files in the project?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have already figured most of it out. The rest can be determined with rather simple compile-time tests, which I highly recommend you try instead of asking here. When that fails or you don't understand what is happening, come back and ask.

Comment: Note, i think this is a very valid question. I'm just suggesting you'll learn better by doing this one yourself.

Comment: I think it is a right thing to just include the files that are needed in your file. If for some reason the includes in the other header files change, you have to do that again all by hand. So including more doesn't seem to be wrong. You could also have a look at `#pragma once`, which is a handy command sometimes.

Comment: -1. I can't see how someone "favor question" this one. The question would be avoided if the asker would check about "translation unit in c++". Besides, it's like asking "what is 'if'?"... something like that. If the answer to that isn't obvious you should go back and review the basics. No offence, but really, I tried to read it several times and couldn't see the brighness in this as few saw, apparently.

Comment: @Poni I'm a professional C++ programmer, and I understand how this can be confusing for a beginner. When you get into projects with any complexity beyond the most basic, this can get confusing fast. It is certainly a very beginner-esque question, but that doesn't make it inappropriate to ask, and certainly not as simple as if().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing much to it. If you use something, you have to include the header declaring the thing you use. About the only exception is [forward declaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) a class/struct or method like:

```
class myclass;
```

if you just need to declare a pointer or reference to the class.

You cannot really rely on other headers including the header you need, by chance. Any day, the maintainer of the other header will realize that he/she don't need that include anymore and remove it.

Comment: +1, never rely on somebody else doing your job; if you need something, include it yourself.

Comment: Also, if you want to declare functions that take or return a `myclass` by value.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: I think all you're missing is the difference between "f2 includes f1", and "f2 is *guaranteed* to include f1". This is particularly important with standard headers, since any standard header is *allowed* to include any other. So if you rely on indirect includes that work on your machine, then your code might fail to compile on a different C++ implementation.

If you have a library where the documentation for "f2.h" says or implies that it includes "f1.h", that means it always will in all compatible versions, so then you can rely on the indirect include. You might do this where you're using one component of a library that fundamentally relies on another component of that library, but where the other component might be used in isolation by other users. For a hypothetical example, "xhtml_parser.h" might reasonably document that it provides all definitions from "xml_parser.h", plus some extra ones.

Question 2: Um, would you like to rephrase the question? "f2 includes f1 and f2 includes f1" isn't what you meant, and there is no "circular linkage". It *can* cause problems if you write headers such that f1 includes f2 and f2 includes f1, because include isn't "linkage", it's pretty much a cut and paste of the contents of the other header file.

So even before f3 come into the picture, circular includes can be problematic:

```
f1.h
----
#ifndef f1_h_included
#define f1_h_included

#include "f2.h"
struct DerivedA : BaseA {};
struct BaseB {};

#endif

f2.h
----
#ifndef f2_h_included
#define f2_h_included

#include "f1.h"
struct BaseA {};
struct DerivedB : BaseB {};

#endif
```

This isn't going to compile no matter which you include of "f1.h" and "f2.h". Assuming f1 is included first, the result after preprocessing looks like this:

```
// contents of f2.h, pasted in at line 4 of f1.h
// (contents of f1.h on the circular include are ignored due to include guard)
struct BaseA {};
struct DerivedB : BaseB {};

// rest of f1.h
struct DerivedA : BaseA {};
struct BaseB {};
```

And so DerivedB specifies a base class which has not yet been defined. Include them the other way around, same problem with DerivedA.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it nailed pretty much.
In order to use input / output streams I need
to include the header file for this.
If you wrote a bigint class that supports a big integer type and you sent
this class to a friend.  Your friend would need to include this in his program in order to make use of it.  So you include something when it is not available to your program.

Answer (score 1):

> However at times I find that I can
>   remove an #include and everything will
>   still compile just fine. From what I
>   can tell this is because other files
>   being included already are including
>   the external definition.

Correct. It's just due to luck, sort of.

> Say we have three .h/.cc pairs:
>   f1.h/.cc, f2.h/.cc, and f3.h/.cc. If
>   f2.h/.cc includes f1.h and f3.h/.cc
>   includes f2.h is it ever necessary for
>   f3.h/.cc to include f1.h or will all
>   of f1.h's definitions be visible to
>   the f3 files when it is included in
>   f2?

You probably meant *f1.h's declarations*, not *definitions*, though you may have some class and template function definitions in there.

Anyway, the answer is no, it will never be necessary. Those declarations will be visible. Preprocessor directives are just simple text insertion. Once you picture that in your head, the expansion becomes easy to comprehend.

> Once again say we have three .h/.cc
>   pairs: f1.h/.cc, f2.h/.cc, and
>   f3.h/.cc. If f2 includes f1 and f2
>   includes f1 and then f3 includes f1 or
>   f2 will the "circular linkage" between
>   and f1 and f2 cause a problem?

Yes, possibly. [Header guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) can alleviate this if the *contents* of the header files are sane. But if the *contents* of f2 rely on the *contents* of f1 and vice versa, then you have a circular dependency in code. This should be resolved by removing that circular dependency, [using](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml) [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

> Do you know of any good resources
>   online I can read to better understand
>   how including something in one file
>   affects subsequent files in the
>   project?

I can recommend [these resources](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Answer (score 0):

First the short answers, explanations follow:

> 1) no it is never necessary to declare #include "f1.h" in f3.h/.cc because this would make an inclusion-cycle (which should not be done)
>
> 2) in   1->2, 1->2->3 there is no cycle, even 2 will only be included once if you use an inclusion-guard  (#ifndef *2*  #define *2*   my2code  #endif)

The implementation is compiler-specific but in general: in a diamond-shape inclusion a good compiler will flatten the inclusion-paths and find the files on the deepest level, the file that is included somewhere but needs not include anything else. It will then continually include those files that are included and only depend on files that were included already. Since this can lead to duplicate inclusions you should always only include headers (.cc's will be linked from same directories without explicit inclusion) and also guard your header-files with inclusion-guards:

e.g. myheader.h:

```
#ifndef _myheader_h_
#define _myheader_h_
int myglobal;
#endif
```

If you were to have a cycle in your inclusions it depends on the compiler: either it tries to find the deepest level and either fail or choose, or it does not try to choose the deepest level at all and include in the order you gave in your files; regardless: if you avoid cycles (you should) and use inclusion-guards you are on the safe side.